# Draw line between location markers in ArCore?

Tags: java, android, location, arcore

Is there a possibility to connect two marker locations with a line? I have two location marker:

```
LocationMarker point1 = new LocationMarker(
    20.501925,
    44.792181,
    new AnnotationRenderer("point1 ")
);

LocationMarker point2 = new LocationMarker(
        20.502972,
        44.790873,
        new AnnotationRenderer("point2 ")
);
```

Any example? I use [ArCore Location](https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will draw a line between two points - the points are associated with anchors in Sceneform - this is adapted from the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816504/334402:

```js
private void drawLine(AnchorNode node1, AnchorNode node2) {
      //Draw a line between two AnchorNodes
        Log.d(TAG,"drawLine");
        Vector3 point1, point2;
        point1 = node1.getWorldPosition();
        point2 = node2.getWorldPosition();


        //First, find the vector extending between the two points and define a look rotation
        //in terms of this Vector.
        final Vector3 difference = Vector3.subtract(point1, point2);
        final Vector3 directionFromTopToBottom = difference.normalized();
        final Quaternion rotationFromAToB =
                Quaternion.lookRotation(directionFromTopToBottom, Vector3.up());
        MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(getApplicationContext(), new Color(0, 255, 244))
                .thenAccept(
                        material -> {
                            /* Then, create a rectangular prism, using ShapeFactory.makeCube() and use the difference vector
                                   to extend to the necessary length.  */
                            Log.d(TAG,"drawLine insie .thenAccept");
                            ModelRenderable model = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                    new Vector3(.01f, .01f, difference.length()),
                                    Vector3.zero(), material);
                            /* Last, set the world rotation of the node to the rotation calculated earlier and set the world position to
                                   the midpoint between the given points . */
                            Anchor lineAnchor = node2.getAnchor();
                            nodeForLine = new Node();
                            nodeForLine.setParent(node1);
                            nodeForLine.setRenderable(model);
                            nodeForLine.setWorldPosition(Vector3.add(point1, point2).scaled(.5f));
                            nodeForLine.setWorldRotation(rotationFromAToB);
                        }
                );

    }
```

**Update**: Full working example available here:

- https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Comment: Thanks, how to transofrm location marker to Anchor mode?

Comment: @FilipKojic - can you explain a little more what you mean, I'm not sure I understand your comment question?

Comment: I used this code snippet, I have no errors. Nodes exist with values like this: `Node(com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode@a8c1dff)`. But the lines are not seen. Tips?