# Draw Line in the direction of camera AR Core in Android?

Tags: android, anchor, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to to add first node and then line drawn in the direction of camera AR fragment center until next anchor node is not added. I mean line follow the center of frame center until the next anchor is not added. Please answer if anyone know.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, maybe the easiest way, is to simply add a node at the centre of the camera preview each frame, or maybe every 0.5 seconds if that proves better, and draw the line between your first node and that node.

You can use some sort of marker or pin for the first node and something different for the end that is still 'drawing'.

You can see an example of drawing a line between two nodes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53372942/334402

which includes a link to a working example: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

The example uses an earlier version of scene form but updating should be straightforward or you can juts use the extract in the above example.