# draw vertical line to camera center in arcore

Tags: android, arcore

i have some horizontal plane, where i set the start point of line i want to draw.

Now i want to make a vertical line from start point to the center of camera, aka ArFragment.
Current i make it as follow

```java
// create an anchor 1 meter away of current camera position and rotation
Anchor anchor = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().getCamera().getPose()
                    .compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f))
                    .extractTranslation());

// create AnchorNode with position data of Anchor
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
// remove anchor to be free change position of AnchorNode
anchorNode.setAnchor(null);
// get local position of new anchor node
Vector3 newLocPos = anchorNode.getLocalPosition();

// get the local position of start node
Vector3 fromVector = fromNode.getLocalPosition();

// since we want to make vertical line, set x and z of new AnchorNode to same as start
newLocPos.x = fromVector.x;
newLocPos.z = fromVector.z;
// set updated position data to new AnchorNode
anchorNode.setLocalPosition(newLocPos);
// set scene as parent to have node in UI
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

// draw line between Nodes
....
```

and this works as expected as long as i can hold smartphone vertical.
When i rotate the camera, the line is no more drawed to middle because the created anchor is no more in the middle of screen.

Is there a official or better way to make a vertical line as expected no matter how i hold a smartphone?

**UPDATE**

now i have reached to create a line by calculate a point of intersection.

```
private static MyPoint calculateIntersectionPoint(MyPoint A, MyPoint B, MyPoint C, MyPoint D) {
    // Line AB represented as a1x + b1y = c1
    double a1 = B.y - A.y;
    double b1 = A.x - B.x;
    double c1 = a1 * (A.x) + b1 * (A.y);

    // Line CD represented as a2x + b2y = c2
    double a2 = D.y - C.y;
    double b2 = C.x - D.x;
    double c2 = a2 * (C.x) + b2 * (C.y);

    double determinant = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;

    if (determinant == 0) {
        // The lines are parallel. This is simplified
        // by returning a pair of FLT_MAX
        return new MyPoint(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    } else {
        double x = (b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / determinant;
        double y = (a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / determinant;
        return new MyPoint(x, y);
    }
}


MyPoint interceptionPoint = calculateIntersectionPoint(
    new MyPoint(line1From.getWorldPosition().x, line1From.getWorldPosition().y),
    new MyPoint(line1To.getWorldPosition().x, line1To.getWorldPosition().y),
    new MyPoint(line2From.getWorldPosition().x, line2From.getWorldPosition().y),
    new MyPoint(line2To.getWorldPosition().x, line2To.getWorldPosition().y));

// get local position of new anchor node
Vector3 newLocPos = anchorNode.getWorldPosition();
// since we want to make vertical line, set x and z of new AnchorNode to same as start
newLocPos.y = (float) interceptionPoint.y;
newLocPos.x = fromVector.x;
newLocPos.z = fromVector.z;

// set updated position data to new AnchorNode
anchorNode.setWorldPosition(newLocPos);
```

The only problem is that the line must be exactly in the middle (right, left) of smartphone

[image: smartphone center on line]

in other case the line is too big or too small

[image: smartphone center right of line]

sphere shows the middle of camera

**UPDATE 2**

Some more explanation

[image]

we set somewhere in xz-room a startpoint of vertical line.

Then we are some away from the line and look at the point where we want the end of line.

Now i look at the problem in 2D and imagine, that my camera start and end point are in same xy-room as line and calculate the endpoint of line.

*The Problem*

my start and end points of camera view has different z as the line i draw.

To find is the point (and his y-value) on camera view vector that is in same xy-room as line (z of line = z of point)

Has anyone idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are removing the anchor from the anchorNode as one of your steps - I think this is because you want to move the anchorNode, but I suspect this is the root of your problem.

The code below will draw a line between any two anchorNodes and remain in place when you rotate the camera (allowing for any small error or movement with your device). This is taken from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816504/334402) and built into the project linked below so you can check it:

```js
private void drawLine(AnchorNode node1, AnchorNode node2) {
      //Draw a line between two AnchorNodes (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816504/334402)
        Log.d(TAG,"drawLine");
        Vector3 point1, point2;
        point1 = node1.getWorldPosition();
        point2 = node2.getWorldPosition();


        //First, find the vector extending between the two points and define a look rotation
        //in terms of this Vector.
        final Vector3 difference = Vector3.subtract(point1, point2);
        final Vector3 directionFromTopToBottom = difference.normalized();
        final Quaternion rotationFromAToB =
                Quaternion.lookRotation(directionFromTopToBottom, Vector3.up());
        MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(getApplicationContext(), new Color(0, 255, 244))
                .thenAccept(
                        material -> {
                            /* Then, create a rectangular prism, using ShapeFactory.makeCube() and use the difference vector
                                   to extend to the necessary length.  */
                            Log.d(TAG,"drawLine insie .thenAccept");
                            ModelRenderable model = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                    new Vector3(.01f, .01f, difference.length()),
                                    Vector3.zero(), material);
                            /* Last, set the world rotation of the node to the rotation calculated earlier and set the world position to
                                   the midpoint between the given points . */
                            Anchor lineAnchor = node2.getAnchor();
                            nodeForLine = new Node();
                            nodeForLine.setParent(node1);
                            nodeForLine.setRenderable(model);
                            nodeForLine.setWorldPosition(Vector3.add(point1, point2).scaled(.5f));
                            nodeForLine.setWorldRotation(rotationFromAToB);
                        }
                );

    }
```

You can see the full code here: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Comment: this is exactly what i make after calculating of node, that i want draw line to. I need the point of **vertical plane** line. horizontal is not the problem.

Comment: Have a look at the project - it allows you move the anchor nodes around using the screen controls and you can do this and you will see the above works fine for vertical or horizontal lines or whatever angle the two nodes make. There is a version  on Play Store if you want to test it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amodtech.ar.lineview&hl=en

Comment: in that applicatio you: 1) sets a both anchors. 2) bind them with line. Tihs is some completly different as doing it in runime. At runtime you don´t know how far is a point you want reach. And this is my problem. The application you reference to is simple and not provide the solution i search. I have already updated my question with fast working solution

Comment: @anatoli - Can you please explain yourself better - the code I referenced creates the anchors at runtime, and allows them be moved at runtime, and draws a line between them at runtime. If this is not what you want then it would be good to explain it more clearly in the question to allow us help you.

Comment: The App creates the anchors only on plane, not in space. After it was created on plane i can move it vertical.

Comment: @anatoli - Again, I'm not 100% sure I understand your comment, but if you mean the app in the link I gave, the anchors are not on the plane and can definitely be moved vertically.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have tried the application. It is not, what i expect. And: it is StackOverflow. i dont need some application from store, i must implement it in my application.

Comment: @anatoli - the app is exactly the same as the code in the answer above and in the GitHub link. All the source is available at the GitHub link. The app link is just a quick way for you to see how it looks on a device.

Comment: I used this code snippet, I have no errors. Nodes exist with values like this: `Node(com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode@a8c1dff)`. But the lines are not seen. Tips?

Comment: @exper_1 Its very hard to comment as you know will your own code better, but the full code is here and this is tested and working: github.com/mickod/LineView It might be that there are some changes in Sceneform version or some other plugin you are using which is causing an issue. One simple quick check is that the line color and transparency etc are visible on your background