# How can I draw a plain white color line (2D) in ArCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to build a measure app with ArCore; and I need to draw lines between anchors in plain color, without any 3D effect (depth, lighting, etc), just plain white color like if it were a 2D line. I've played a bit with ArCore `Material` class, and `ShapeFactory.makeCube()` with no results.

Can you please point me out in the right direction?

Comment: This is not actually 2D, but the effect can be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816504/334402. - See an example in the image here: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Comment: That's what I've done so far, but it still has lighting effects on it when you move around the anchors or the camera view. I'm looking to draw an always white (#FFFFFF) line, no matter the angle, the view, or lighting conditions. Thank you though.

Comment: I suspect that will be tricky as the shadowing and lighting is most likely tightly integrated with the rendering. You might be able to use a ViewRenderable (https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable) and size and position it as you need, but that will be complex also.