# Draw line instead of rendering Anchor in arcore

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I am new to AR, I am working on an APP using ARCore using this one [AR-REMOTE-SUPPORT](https://github.com/ysc1995/ARCoreAgora)
When I am drawing it from my screen it is creating default android anchor, I want line instead of default android anchor.
How can I achieve this.

here is the function which is placing Anchors on the screen

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (mSession == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Notify ARCore session that the view size changed so that the perspective matrix and
        // the video background can be properly adjusted.
        mDisplayRotationHelper.updateSessionIfNeeded(mSession);

        try {
            // Obtain the current frame from ARSession. When the configuration is set to
            // UpdateMode.BLOCKING (it is by default), this will throttle the rendering to the
            // camera framerate.
            Frame frame = mSession.update();
            Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

            // Handle taps. Handling only one tap per frame, as taps are usually low frequency
            // compared to frame rate.
            MotionEvent tap = queuedSingleTaps.poll();
            if (tap != null && camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
                    // Check if any plane was hit, and if it was hit inside the plane polygon
                    Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
                    // Creates an anchor if a plane or an oriented point was hit.
                    if ((trackable instanceof Plane && ((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose()))
                            || (trackable instanceof Point
                            && ((Point) trackable).getOrientationMode()
                            == Point.OrientationMode.ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL)) {
                        // Hits are sorted by depth. Consider only closest hit on a plane or oriented point.
                        // Cap the number of objects created. This avoids overloading both the
                        // rendering system and ARCore.
                        if (anchors.size() >= 250) {
                            anchors.get(0).detach();
                            anchors.remove(0);
                        }
                        // Adding an Anchor tells ARCore that it should track this position in
                        // space. This anchor is created on the Plane to place the 3D model
                        // in the correct position relative both to the world and to the plane.
                        anchors.add(hit.createAnchor());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Draw background.
            mBackgroundRenderer.draw(frame);

            // If not tracking, don't draw 3d objects.
            if (camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.PAUSED) {
                return;
            }

            // Get projection matrix.
            float[] projmtx = new float[16];
            camera.getProjectionMatrix(projmtx, 0, 0.1f, 100.0f);

            // Get camera matrix and draw.
            float[] viewmtx = new float[16];
            camera.getViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);

            // Compute lighting from average intensity of the image.
            final float lightIntensity = frame.getLightEstimate().getPixelIntensity();

            if (isShowPointCloud()) {
                // Visualize tracked points.
                PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
                mPointCloud.update(pointCloud);
                mPointCloud.draw(viewmtx, projmtx);

                // Application is responsible for releasing the point cloud resources after
                // using it.
                pointCloud.release();
            }

            // Check if we detected at least one plane. If so, hide the loading message.
            if (mMessageSnackbar != null) {
                for (Plane plane : mSession.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                    if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                            && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                        hideLoadingMessage();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isShowPlane()) {
                // Visualize planes.
                mPlaneRenderer.drawPlanes(
                        mSession.getAllTrackables(Plane.class), camera.getDisplayOrientedPose(), projmtx);
            }

            // Visualize anchors created by touch.
            float scaleFactor = 1.0f;

            for (Anchor anchor : anchors) {
                if (anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    continue;
                }
                // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
                // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.
                anchor.getPose().toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, 0);


                // Update and draw the model and its shadow.
                mVirtualObject.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, mScaleFactor);
                //mVirtualObjectShadow.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, scaleFactor);
                mVirtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
                mVirtualObjectShadow.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
            }

            sendARViewMessage();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // Avoid crashing the application due to unhandled exceptions.
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

TIA

Comment: I use the same project, I can't draw the lines. This project does not use arFragment. Were you able to solve?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to draw a line in ARCore is to create it between two anchor points.

The line itself is generally a 3D object also.

Here is a tested working example, based on the nice approach in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816504/334402

```js
private void drawLine(AnchorNode node1, AnchorNode node2) {
      //Draw a line between two AnchorNodes (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816504/334402)
        Log.d(TAG,"drawLine");
        Vector3 point1, point2;
        point1 = node1.getWorldPosition();
        point2 = node2.getWorldPosition();


        //First, find the vector extending between the two points and define a look rotation
        //in terms of this Vector.
        final Vector3 difference = Vector3.subtract(point1, point2);
        final Vector3 directionFromTopToBottom = difference.normalized();
        final Quaternion rotationFromAToB =
                Quaternion.lookRotation(directionFromTopToBottom, Vector3.up());
        MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(getApplicationContext(), new Color(0, 255, 244))
                .thenAccept(
                        material -> {
                            /* Then, create a rectangular prism, using ShapeFactory.makeCube() and use the difference vector
                                   to extend to the necessary length.  */
                            Log.d(TAG,"drawLine insie .thenAccept");
                            ModelRenderable model = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                    new Vector3(.01f, .01f, difference.length()),
                                    Vector3.zero(), material);
                            /* Last, set the world rotation of the node to the rotation calculated earlier and set the world position to
                                   the midpoint between the given points . */
                            Anchor lineAnchor = node2.getAnchor();
                            nodeForLine = new Node();
                            nodeForLine.setParent(node1);
                            nodeForLine.setRenderable(model);
                            nodeForLine.setWorldPosition(Vector3.add(point1, point2).scaled(.5f));
                            nodeForLine.setWorldRotation(rotationFromAToB);
                        }
                );

    }
```

You can see the full source here: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Comment: It seems that sceneform, besides being no longer supported, is not even compatible with androidx, is there any other way to create the lines?

Comment: If you need the lines just to be on the screen you can just use the graphics functions to draw the line on a canvas. You can also do it on the canvas of an overlay view if you want to keep them separate.

Comment: I need the lines to be anchored to various points. I am working on this project: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java

Comment: I managed to implement it, I have no errors. Nodes exist with values like this: `Node (com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode@a8c1dff)`. But the lines are not seen. Tips?

Comment: Its very hard to comment as you know will your own code better, but the full code is here and this is tested and working: https://github.com/mickod/LineView It might be that there are some changes in Sceneform version or some other plugin you are using which is causing an issue. One simple quick check is that the line color and transparency etc are visible on your background.

Comment: The problem is that LineView and everything online uses arFragment, I don't use it. The problem could be this: `nodeToAdd.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());`
I can't do anything like that. 
I can't draw without using arFragment.
I also use the Agora project which is based on the official google project https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java

Comment: @exper_1 - I think you might be best riding your own specific question and including as much detail and code examples as you can to make it clear. That way a wider audience will be able to help you also.

Comment: I've done it, thank you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046101/how-to-draw-a-line-between-anchors-on-the-plane-with-arcore-without-arfragment