# How to draw a line between anchors on the plane with ARcore without arFragment

Tags: android, arcore

I'm building my app around this [Agora ARcore Demo](https://github.com/ysc1995/ARCoreAgora) based on [Google's hello_ar_java Sample APP](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java).

This application, capture user's taps and check if any planes in the scene were found. If so, create an anchor at that point.

I would like to draw a line between the various anchors.

Everything I find on the web uses sceneForm and arFragment.

At the moment I have managed to implement sceneForm without arFragment but the line is not showing, probably because of
of this method that I don't know how to replace without arFragment: `nodeToAdd.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());`

To implement sceneform in my project I'm taking a cue from this project [LineView](https://github.com/mickod/LineView)
Are there any other methods without using sceneform?

This is how I am proceeding:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (mSession == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Notify ARCore session that the view size changed so that the perspective matrix and
    // the video background can be properly adjusted.
    mDisplayRotationHelper.updateSessionIfNeeded(mSession);

    try {
        // Obtain the current frame from ARSession. When the configuration is set to
        // UpdateMode.BLOCKING (it is by default), this will throttle the rendering to the
        // camera framerate.
        Frame frame = mSession.update();
        Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

        // Handle taps. Handling only one tap per frame, as taps are usually low frequency
        // compared to frame rate.
        MotionEvent tap = queuedSingleTaps.poll();
        if (tap != null && camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
            for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
                // Check if any plane was hit, and if it was hit inside the plane polygon
                Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
                // Creates an anchor if a plane or an oriented point was hit.
                if ((trackable instanceof Plane && ((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose()))
                        || (trackable instanceof Point
                        && ((Point) trackable).getOrientationMode()
                        == Point.OrientationMode.ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL)) {
                    // Hits are sorted by depth. Consider only closest hit on a plane or oriented point.
                    // Cap the number of objects created. This avoids overloading both the
                    // rendering system and ARCore.
                    if (anchors.size() >= 250) {
                        anchors.get(0).detach();
                        anchors.remove(0);
                    }
                    // Adding an Anchor tells ARCore that it should track this position in
                    // space. This anchor is created on the Plane to place the 3D model
                    // in the correct position relative both to the world and to the plane.
                    anchors.add(hit.createAnchor());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw background.
        mBackgroundRenderer.draw(frame);

        // If not tracking, don't draw 3d objects.
        if (camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.PAUSED) {
            return;
        }

        // Get projection matrix.
        float[] projmtx = new float[16];
        camera.getProjectionMatrix(projmtx, 0, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // Get camera matrix and draw.
        float[] viewmtx = new float[16];
        camera.getViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);

        // Compute lighting from average intensity of the image.
        final float lightIntensity = frame.getLightEstimate().getPixelIntensity();

        if (isShowPointCloud()) {
            // Visualize tracked points.
            PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
            mPointCloud.update(pointCloud);
            mPointCloud.draw(viewmtx, projmtx);

            // Application is responsible for releasing the point cloud resources after
            // using it.
            pointCloud.release();
        }

        // Check if we detected at least one plane. If so, hide the loading message.
        if (mMessageSnackbar != null) {
            for (Plane plane : mSession.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                        && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    hideLoadingMessage();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isShowPlane()) {
            // Visualize planes.
            mPlaneRenderer.drawPlanes(
                    mSession.getAllTrackables(Plane.class), camera.getDisplayOrientedPose(), projmtx);
        }

        // Visualize anchors created by touch.
        float scaleFactor = 1.0f;

        for (Anchor anchor : anchors) {
            if (anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                continue;
            }
            // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
            // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.
            anchor.getPose().toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, 0);


            // Update and draw the model and its shadow.
            mVirtualObject.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, mScaleFactor);
            mVirtualObjectShadow.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, scaleFactor);
            mVirtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
            mVirtualObjectShadow.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
        }

        sendARViewMessage();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Avoid crashing the application due to unhandled exceptions.
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
 public void drawLineButton(View view) {
    AnchorNode nodeToAdd;
    for (Anchor anchor : anchors) {
        anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        anchorNodeList.add(anchorNode);
        //this is the problem imho
        //nodeToAdd.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        numberOfAnchors++;

    }

    if (numberOfAnchors == 2 ) {
        drawLine(anchorNodeList.get(0), anchorNodeList.get(1));
    }
}
```

Here the Nodes exist and are real. I don't find any errors, and the lines don't show:

```
private void drawLine(AnchorNode node1, AnchorNode node2) {
    //Here the knots exist and are real. I don't find any errors, and the lines don't show
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Vector3 point1, point2;
            point1 = node1.getWorldPosition();
            point2 = node2.getWorldPosition();

            //First, find the vector extending between the two points and define a look rotation
            //in terms of this Vector.
            final Vector3 difference = Vector3.subtract(point1, point2);
            final Vector3 directionFromTopToBottom = difference.normalized();
            final Quaternion rotationFromAToB =
                    Quaternion.lookRotation(directionFromTopToBottom, Vector3.up());
            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(getApplicationContext(), new Color(0, 255, 244))
                    .thenAccept(
                            material -> {
                        /* Then, create a rectangular prism, using ShapeFactory.makeCube() and use the difference vector
                               to extend to the necessary length.  */
                                Log.d(TAG,"drawLine insie .thenAccept");
                                ModelRenderable model = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                        new Vector3(.01f, .01f, difference.length()),
                                        Vector3.zero(), material);
                        /* Last, set the world rotation of the node to the rotation calculated earlier and set the world position to
                               the midpoint between the given points . */
                                Anchor lineAnchor = node2.getAnchor();
                                nodeForLine = new Node();
                                nodeForLine.setParent(node1);
                                nodeForLine.setRenderable(model);
                                nodeForLine.setWorldPosition(Vector3.add(point1, point2).scaled(.5f));
                                nodeForLine.setWorldRotation(rotationFromAToB);
                            }
                    );



        }
    });


}
```

this is the example of my point1,poin2 and directionFromTopToBottom in the `drawLine()` function:

```
point1: [x=0.060496617, y=-0.39098215, z=-0.21526277]
point2: [x=0.05695567, y=-0.39132282, z=-0.33304527]
directionFromTopToBottom: [x=0.030049745, y=0.0028910497, z=0.9995442]
```

Comment: Can someone explain below line of code? 
final Vector3 directionFromTopToBottom = difference.normalized();
            final Quaternion rotationFromAToB =
                    Quaternion.lookRotation(directionFromTopToBottom, Vector3.up());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not calling your `drawLineButton()` function, is it? Anyway, it looks like you're trying to use some things from Sceneform (MaterialFactory, ModelRenderable, etc) while doing some pure OpenGL rendering as done in the **hello_ar_java**.

Mixing those will result in nothing good since Sceneform uses filament as rendering engine which could use OpenGL or Vulkan. So either go fully with Sceneform or fully with OpenGL (and understand how OpenGL and Android work).

Now, if you want to continue with **hello_ar_java** sample, follow an OpenGL tutorial in order to be able to generate a vertex for each anchor and draw them with **GL_LINES** with the line size you like. Here's a good OpenGL tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/ I recommend going through **all** the Getting Started section, but just keep in mind that it is OpenGL and Android uses OpenGL ES, there are some differences but the computer graphics principles are the same.

Comment: the drawLineButton function is called on click from the layout file, but I also tried from code with setOnClickListener. I was hoping to succeed by merging the two systems, if not possible then I will try to use GL_LINES. At this point I wanted to try to solve as I did, I have all the necessary values but the line is not visible.

Comment: But your current approach would never work since your onDrawFrame() function never interacts with Sceneform, so it will never render anything. But as I was saying, avoid this path as it cannot bring anything good to mix 2 rendering mechanisms that assume they are alone. I am not even sure if it would be possible at all to render with Sceneform on a custom and independent GLSurfaceView.

Comment: Not sure why onDrawFrame() doesn't interact with SceneForm, but I follow your advice, I'll try to use GL_LINES.

Comment: Basically with hello_ar_java you have your own GLSurfaceView with your own OpenGL context&configuration. Sceneform also creates its OpenGL context+configuration, and they are not even using GLSurfaceView, but SurfaceView directly. Also, they probably clean the screen when starting rendering (same as the sample does with GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);, so even if you got Sceneform to render on your GLSurfaceView, currently one would remove the content that the previous had rendered. That's why I say that mixing them will bring nothing good.

Comment: Hello @exper_1, did you get any success with OPENGL  ? I am facing same issue that line is not getting drawn.

Comment: Hello @exper_1 and Yesha Shah i am also facing same issue, if you guys found any solutions please let me know, i am also searching for same from last 10 days. thank you.